# Use PHP to embed JSON for use by Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, json, wordpress

I'm working on using React (javascript) inside a WordPress plugin but my plugin requires some data retrieved from the database. I could probably retrieve the required data in javascript using jquery or an API call, but since the data will be static, it seemed more efficient to embed the data using php prior to rendering the DOM element with javascript.

I tried the following, but the `<script>` tag containing the json never appears in the DOM.

```
<?php

$events = \Civi\Api4\Event::get()
  ->addSelect('*')
  ->addOrderBy('start_date', 'ASC')
  ->setLimit(25)
  ->execute();

  echo "<script type=\"application/json\" id=\"eventList\">";
  echo json_encode($events);
  echo "</script>";
?>

<div id="civi-react-events">
    <h2>Loading...</h2>
</div>
```

### Update

It turns out the code above works. It turned out to be a cache issue. Ctrl-Refresh is your friend.

Thank you to those who took the time to respond.

Comment: Are you sure ‍that `$events` contains an array of events? What is the return type of `execute` method?

Comment: You are actually certain that it _does not appear in DOM_ (as in, verified in HTML source), or just that your code can't access it? Is it possible that your environment has output buffering on, and the buffer is modified at some point, leading to your script/JSON not appearing?

Comment: I use this query in another context, so I do know that it returns an array. I did check the source of the HTML page to verify that it wasn't there. I haven't even attempted to access it with my script yet.

Comment: Thanks for your update. If that's the case, the question is unlikely to be of much use to anyone else, it would be better to delete it

Comment: I don't believe I am able to delete it. It is a working example of using PHP to embed json in the DOM, so it may be of value.

Comment: A question is supposed to demonstrate a problem though...solutions go in the Answers area :-). I've just noticed the answer below has an upvote on it, which is likely why you can't delete the question. Is the answer in any way relevant to what your real problem was in the end? It doesn't seem like it would be

Comment: I gave it an upvote because, I have no issue with the question being deleted, I just don't have the ability to do so.

Comment: Might be an idea to have your dev server running without cache. For Apache, e.g. `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"`, possibly in a `<FilesMatch "\.(html|js|css)$">` or whatever that you don't want to have stale.

Comment: `I gave it an upvote because, I have no issue with the question being deleted, I just don't have the ability to do so. `...no, the question cannot be deleted _because_ you upvoted that answer - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, `json_encode` returns tags, texts, etc. with a wrong format. It may lead to break the `script` tag To ensure the json is fine to use, use the [json_encode flags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php). I personally recommend using the following flags:

```
<?php

$jsonExportConst = JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK;

$eventsJson = json_encode($events, $jsonExportConsts);

echo "<script type=\"application/json\" id=\"eventList\">{$eventsJson}</script>"
```